# Enforced margin space?

Tags: html, css

In this HTML code; I've removed all the margins, but there is stile about 4px above the footer. I don't know where it comes from?
[image]
Here is the HTML with the styling

```css
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 body {
   width: 900px;
   background-color: yellow;
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding: 0;
 }
 header {
   width: 900px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 80px;
   background-color: brown;
 }
 nav {
   width: 900px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: black;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 section {
   width: 650px;
   height: 850px;
   background-color: darkgray;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 aside {
   width: 250px;
   height: 850px;
   background-color: #6B6862;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0px auto;
 }
 footer {
   margin: 0px;
   width: 900px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: black;
 }
 .by {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<header>
</header>
<nav>
</nav>

<section>
</section>
<aside>
</aside>
<footer>
  <div class="by">
    Author
  </div>
</footer>
```

Also how to vertically centralize the word "Author" in the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the vertical-align property on the align element. Since you set the display to inline-block, there's room left for descender content.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: brown;
}
nav {
  width: 900px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
  width: 650px;
  height: 850px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
aside {
  width: 250px;
  height: 850px;
  background-color: #6B6862;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  vertical-align:top;
}
footer {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
.by {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
<nav>
</nav>

<section>
</section>
<aside>
</aside>
<footer>
  <div class="by">
    Author
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.by` author text is probably causing a margin collapse bug.

Try adding this css to `.by`:

```
.by {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: There is no classes named he!

Answer (score 0):

For align text vertically center :

```
   footer
    {
     width:900px;
     height:50px;
     background-color:black;
    display: table;
     position: relative;
     }
    .by
    {
     color:white;
      text-align:center;
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;
     }


   And for space issue this could fix :
   aside
  {
   width:250px;
    height:850px;
    background-color:#6B6862;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:right;
    }
```